# What software can I use on my pi to take a screenshot?

Tags: screen

I have created a game that only runs on a pi and I want to upload to the Pi Store, but I need to take a screenshot of the game. Anyone know some good software for taking screenshots on a pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several programs to take screenshots. One that I have used is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). Install by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

To grab the whole desktop:

```
import -window root screen.png
```

---

Another one that I use is [scrot](http://freecode.com/projects/scrot), a useful, simple command line utility. To install:

```
sudo apt-get install scrot
```

Then run `scrot -s` and click on the window you want a screenshot of. You will get a timestamp-based `.png` in the working directory of your terminal. See `man scrot` for more options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use >Scrot<

Install:

> sudo apt-get install
>    scrot

To take a screenshot press >Print Scr< as in Windows, and go to filemanager to see your screenshot.

To display  the list of scrot command:

> sudo scrot -h

Comment: the page you gave url to is not 100k piece of text with plenty of embedded pictures, therefore it might be much more helpful, if you copy-paste the contents to save hundreds of people about 10 seconds when clicking the link and waiting for the content to appear. also it will keep your answer relevant when the original web page will disappear.

Comment: Okay, i changed it to something that can be useful, and that was not mentioned in other answer for not delet my answer or leave it as a thing that can't help neither a little.